# How to transfer remote files in Aptana Studio 3 when connected via Connections Manager?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

How to connect to remote files from Aptana Studio 3 without connecting to FTP. On rt-click I only get "Run web deployment wizard" and no other options like "Transfer files and all other options". And I am connected in connections manager.

Comment: How do you want to transfer that isn't FTP?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your project is not connected.  If you follow through with the "Run Web Deployment Wizard" it will ask you for your ftp credentials, etc.  After that, you should be able to edit the files in the project and transfer them without bothering with the ftp information again.  I think that the wizard will come up one time for each project you connect to a remote server.

I have a remote project and when I right-click, I get options for transfer of files.  Your connected project should have a subfolder called "Connections" which contains all the files in the project. I wanted to upload screenshots of my project view, but I don't have the permissions yet.